# Integrate Google Drive into Android I can insert a file, but I can't delete what I insert

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api

I have read the instructions step by step
 https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android

And I have run the example then it works. When insert a file. It will make a lot duplicated file on google drive . I insert "test.db" many time on google drive. It create a lot of test.db. Therefore before I start insert "test.db", I want to delete the "test.db" first.
But the following code still not work. Could any body tell me why?

```
private void deleteFileOnDrive() {
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {            
                Files.List fileList = service.files().list().setQ("title = 'test.db'");    
                FileList files = fileList.execute(); 
                ArrayList<File> myFiles = new ArrayList<File>();
                myFiles.addAll(files.getItems());
                for (File myFile : myFiles) {
                    deleteFile(service, myFile.getId());
                }
            }
            catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException e) {
                startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                finish();

            }
        }
    });
    t.start();
}

private static void deleteFile(Drive service, String fileId) {
    try {
        service.files().delete(fileId).execute();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
    }
 }
```

I spend 2hours to integrate the dropbox into our android app. It works fine. But I have spent 2 days to integrate google drive into our android app. It still not be finish yet. sigh~

Comment: In what way is it not working. Would probably help to post the logcat

Comment: No exception No error, but the files test.db still there. I use chrome to check the google drive. Then delete them manually via google drive web interface. It showed  these items can't removed. Why ? Create the file via resultFile = service.files().insert(body, fileContent).execute(); can't be delete???

Comment: I did see something like that when I did some work on Drive. It just seemed to delete itself after a while. In order to do the testing I changed the file name I was uploading so it would create a new version. Might be worth trying that and then try deleting it.

Comment: I think if I remember correctly it also returns an int based on the result for the delete. It might be worth to do int result = service.delete(....) and step through the code in the debugger and see what it does and check the result

Comment: Hi Boardy, Thanks very much for your reply, These files were disapear several hours later. The above code were correct. But google drive still show the deleted files on web interface. I may try to use update  instead of delete and insert. Google drive api is so hard to use. Dropbox is better than google drive in this respect.